# DOCPAD How can I exclude files from being pushed into the out-folder

Tags: docpad

Example: I have a `config.rb`-file under `src/files/config.rb`

How can I exclude this file being pushed by docpad into `out/config.rb`

Is there an exclude-command for the config-file like in jekyll for example? `exclude: makelive.sh, ideas.txt, newpost.rb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the various [ignore* configuration options](http://docpad.org/docs/config) to accomplish what you need.

On the surface, the `ignorePaths` seems like it would be the easiest solution if you only have one or two files you don't want included, but in fact, it seems to operate based on absolute paths, which is inconvenient.  So I'd probably use the `ignoreCustomPatterns` option to specify regexs that match the files you don't want copied.

```
# Ignore Custom Patterns
# Can be set to a regex of custom patterns to ignore from the scanning process
ignoreCustomPatterns: /config.rb/
```